# Ghost Slack program that I cannot find its path

Tags: 20.04, uninstall

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I want to remove Slack app. [link to slack app](https://slack.com/)

I tried sudo apt-get remove slack. It reports no error and it seems to delete some files. But still, I can find Slack from the dashboard.

Even worse, I was trying to use `htop` to locate the path of Slack that I just opened. Guess what, it gives me a fake path that doesn't exist, called `/app/extra/lib/slack/slack`
Then I tried to locate that path:

```
cd /app/extra/lib/slack
bash: cd: /app/extra/lib/slack: No such file or directory
```

where is it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have installed [Slack as flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.slack.Slack), your `htop` output shows it in clear:

> ```
> 0:00.05 /usr/libexec/flatpak-bwrap --args 34 slack
> ```

To remove it use command below:

```
flatpak remove flathub com.slack.Slack
```

Comment: life saver!!!!!