# uninstall openboard from Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: software-uninstall

I have openboard showing on my list of favourites, which I would like to uninstall.
I have tried the following:

```
$ sudo apt remove openboard
[sudo] password for user1:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openboard' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 10 not to upgrade.
```

and

```
$ sudo apt purge openboard
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openboard' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 10 not to upgrade.
```

but the software remains on favourites and I can still run it.

when I run the software I can view it running as follows:

```
$ ps -aux | grep "openb*"
user1 9615 0.4 0.0 3620 1128 ? S 22:14 0:00 bwrap --args 37 openboard
user1 9626 0.2 0.0 3704 1436 ? S 22:14 0:00 bwrap --args 37 openboard
user1 9627 8.5 0.4 2017184 140220 ? Sl 22:14 0:00 openboard
user1 9678 0.0 0.0 9152 2404 pts/2 S+ 22:14 0:00 grep --color=auto openb*
```

Question is, how to completely remove openboard ?

Comment: If it's a snap - it certainly is if you installed it from the Ubuntu Software - then `sudo snap remove <packagename>`

Comment: Thanks, ran ```$ sudo snap remove openboard
openboard removed```, but the software remains and I am still able to run it.

Comment: How you remove something depends upon how you originally installed it. Edit your Question above to include the complete output of `whereis openboard`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [seems to be](https://askubuntu.com/q/1356588/66509) [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/ch.openboard.OpenBoard), then remove it as flatpak by

```
flatpak remove ch.openboard.OpenBoard
```